# Present Alert on ViewController only once

Tags: ios, swift

I am having various ViewControllers in my app. On one of them I want a alert to be displayed on load of the VC once to the user.

I have followed the instructions to set a glob var under the import section:

```
var disalert:Bool = true
```

and in the function I got:

```
if disalert {

    let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "How-to use Holiday List", message: "message here", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    //Create and add the Cancel action

    //Create and an option action
    let nextAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { action -> Void in

    }
    actionSheetController.addAction(nextAction)
    //Add a text field
    //Present the AlertController
    self.presentViewController(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    disalert = false

}
```

The alert is not presented whilst the app is open. When I restart the phone or quit the app completely its again there.

Thank you!

Comment: When you restart the app the variables that you set are reset too. They are only held in memory. You need to store them to disk using something like NSUserDefaults.

Comment: You need to load/store the `disalert` to a persistent storage like the NSUserDefaults for example, so that the value will be "remembered" even after you restart your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before showing the alert, wherever you want to show it, check the value against the "disalert" key in your userDefaults with this statement:

```
var disalert: Bool = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults.boolForKey("disalert");

if disalert {
// The alert has already been shown so no need to show it again

}

else

{
// The alert hasn't been shown yet. Show it now and save in the userDefaults
// After showing the alert write this line of code

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults.setBool(true, forKey: "disalert")

}
```

Comment: So no other specification necessary?

Comment: Probably no other specifications because the value that u r saving in the NSUserDefaults will remain there as long as u do not remove that value yourself or delete the app. And when there is no value present for that key, the method will return false and there the alert will be shown. Please ask if I'm not clear in my answer.

Comment: override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool){
let disalert:Bool=NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("disalert")
if disalert{
NSLog("Alert shown already.")
}else{
var alert: UIAlertController=UIAlertController(title:"Title",message:"Some message here.",preferredStyle:.Alert)
let action: UIAlertAction=UIAlertAction(title:"Action",style:.Default,handler:{ (action)->Void in
NSLog("Action button pressed.")
})
alert.addAction(action)
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "disalert")
}
}

Comment: Paste the above code in your view controller as it is. I have tested it and it works just fine. NO issues at all

Answer (score 3):

If I am reading your question properly, my suggestion would be to user NSUserDefaults to save a key when the user first opens the view. Then just use an IF statement to decide whether an alertView should be displayed.

Comment: Ok, I just googled a bit. Where to declare the default? Within any object or in AppDelegate?

Answer (score -1):

[Adeel's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31651371) worked for me, with a slight improvement:

```
var disalert: Bool = 

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("disalert");

if disalert {
// The alert has already been shown so no need to show it again

}

else

{
// The alert hasn't been shown yet. Show it now and save in the userDefaults
// After showing the alert write this line of code

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults.setBool(true, forKey: "disalert")

}
```

NSUserDefaults cried for the following: NSUserDefaults.**standardUserDefaults()**

Comment: I marked -1 for error :( please excuse me, Iask to moderator if is possible to eliminate it ... thanks in advance and excuse me another once, sorry....